# DIY cartridge stops on git push

Tags: openshift

I've been developing an application for some weeks, and it's been running in a OpenShift small gear with DIY 0.1 + PostgreSQL cartridges for several days, including ~5 new deployments. Everything was ok and a new deploy stopped and started everything in seconds.

Nevertheless today pushing master as usual stops the cartridge and it won't start. This is the trace:

```
Counting objects: 2688, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1930/1930), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2080/2080), 10.76 MiB | 99 KiB/s, done.
Total 2080 (delta 1300), reused 13 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping DIY cartridge
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Logging in with ssh and running the `start` action hook manually fails because database is stopped. Restarting the gear makes everything work again.

The failing deployment has nothing to do with it, since it only adds a few lines of code, nothing about configuration or anything that might break the boot.

Logs (at `$OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR`) reveal nothing. Quota usage seems fine:

```
Cartridges               Used Limit
---------------------- ------ -----
diy-0.1 postgresql-9.2 0.6 GB  1 GB
```

Any suggestions about what could I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, dumb mistake. My *last* working deployment involved a change in the binary name, which now matches the gear name. `stop` script, with `ps` `grep` and so on was wrong, not killing only the application but also the connection. Changing it fixed the issue.

Solution inspired by [this blogpost](http://www.hfaber.com/post/134988456944/git-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly).